# Symfony2, How to do some action via email?

Tags: symfony, security

I would like to access secure part of my web application via some auto generated emails.

The senario would be something like below :

System generates some emails for `Approval` action and send them to the related users; I have the controller in the secured area of my project and it is working when a user is logged in.

I would like to make this happen via some links to be easy for the user to do so.

In other words, How securely access a controller via a link existing in an email ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are at least two solutions :

1) The simplier is to make a link to the secured area. When the user clicks on this link, he will be redirected to the login page (if he is not logged).

2) You can use a confirmation token in your url link like FOSUserBundle do for the email confirmation : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php#L99